# An analog of the. divisibility by 9 test for other bases

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $b>1$ be a integer , and $n=(d_kd_{k-1}....d_1d_0)_b$. Show that $$(b-1)|n\iff(b-1)|d_0+d_1+d_2+.....d_k$$

As I know that this is true for when $b=10$, but I can't prove this for any positive integer.

Comment: Hint: it'll be enough to show $b-1$ divides $n-(d_0+d_1+\dots+d_k)$ (why?). For that, note $n=b^kd_k+b^{k-1}d_{k-1}+\dots+b^2d_2+bd_1+d_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$n=(d_kd_{k-1}....d_1d_0)_b=\sum_{i=0}^{k} d_i b^i=
\sum_{i=0}^{k} d_i (b^i-1)+\sum_{i=0}^{k} d_i.$$
Is it true that $(b-1)$ divides $(b^i-1)$?

Comment: ..thanks but i am little not understand your hint.

Comment: @P suresh See my edited answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Robertz..yes (b-1) divides ($b^i$-1)

Comment: now i understand one part

Comment: @P suresh OK. This implies that $(b-1)$ divides the difference $n-\sum_{i=0}^{k} d_i$.

Comment: @Robertz..yes ..

Comment: @Robertz..as wojowu hint ..this is enough

Comment: @Robertz...i think its clear thanks very much for your help..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier in terms of congruences:

$b\equiv 1\mod(b-1)$, hence for any $i\in\mathbf N$, $\;b^i\equiv1\mod(b-1)$.

Now the positional notation $\;n=(d_kd_{k-1}\dots d_1d_0)_b$ means that $$n=\sum_{i=0}^kd_i b^i\equiv\sum_{i=0}^kd_i\mod(b-1).$$
Hernce $n$ is divisible by $b-1$, i.e. congruent to $0$ modulo $b-1$, if and only if $\;\sum_{i=0}^kd_i\;$ is.

*Added:* Similarly, you can prove that $n$ is divisible by $b+1$ if and only if the alternating sum: $\;d_0-d_1+\dotsm+(-1)^kd_k$, is.